# Android: Where can I check the latest version of dagger hilt?

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I'm looking at the `developer doc` for the latest version to use `Dagger Hilt`, but I can't find a version similar to what I've seen on the web.

In other web sample code that uses `hilt`, I added hilt version `2.28` or `2.41` to gradle, but I can't find any similar version in [developer doc](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/hilt#hilt-navigation-compose_version_100_2).

Did something change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also check the maven repository: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.dagger/hilt-android

It looks like the latest is 2.41, although the Google Docs haven't been updated.

Answer (score 6):

Considering this document the latest version should be 2.38.1

Document: https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android

I do not think anything is changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the latest version of dagger hilt here:
https://github.com/google/dagger/releases

Despite the fact that the repository is called Dagger, it also contains updates for Hilt

There you will also find release notes where you can read exactly what has been changed in the latest updates.